# MYSQL: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id_employee' in 'from clause'

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

i) order_details :

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
>   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `content` text,
>   `id_employee` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   KEY `FK_id_employee` (`id_employee`),
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_id_employee` FOREIGN KEY (`id_employee`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```

ii) employees   :

```
 CREATE TABLE `employees` (   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `firstname` text NOT NULL,   `lastname` text NOT NULL,   `salary` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

I want to get firstname, lastname and details of order that employee 3 is responsible for. I used this :

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, content FROM order_details INNER JOIN employees USING (id_employee) WHERE id_employee = 3;
```

but I'm getting this error message: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id_employee' in 'from clause'` and have no clue where it came from :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `USING` the name of the column must be the same in both tables. You do not have an `id_employee` in the `employee` table. So you should use this instead which uses the `ON` condition to join the two tables:

```
SELECT e.lastname, e.firstnam, o.content 
FROM order_details o
INNER JOIN employees e
  ON  o.id_employee = e.id 
WHERE o.id_employee = 3;
```

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist
>   in both tables. If tables a and b both contain columns c1, c2, and c3,
>   the following join compares corresponding columns from the two tables

Answer (score 2):

`order_details` does have a `id_employee` column, but the employees tables does not. Use

```
SELECT lastname, firstnam, content
FROM order_details od
INNER JOIN employees e on od.id_employee = e.id
WHERE od.id_employee = 3;
```

in order to join on the different column names. You could use `using` if the column names were the same in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You are **JOINing** by USING (id_employee)  but this is not present in your employees table. So join employees id with that

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt of missing columns 
check what you typed in when creating the table

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

or to just see the columns of the table

```
 DESC table_name
```

this can be helpfull when debugging for such errors.